# DataBodyRange causes error when table is empty

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening,

I have the following button to save that register information of a form, nevertheless when initiating the first record it throws me error: the error has occurred 91 variable of object or block with not established and indicates the highlighted thing:

After it works correctly when there are already inserted values the problem is only for the first record. Please, could you help me solve the error?

Thank you very much.

```
 Private Sub cmdguardar_Click()

 Dim names As Variant
 Dim IDs As Variant
 Dim LROT As Long
 Dim Celda As Range
 Dim i%
 Dim row As ListRow
 Dim table As ListObject

'We declare the table
 Set tabla = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")


names = Split(txtname, vbCrLf)
 IDs = Split(txtID, vbCrLf)

 'We go through each name (if there is only 1, it does not matter, it will 
 only make one cycle)

  For i = 0 To UBound(nombres)

 'Last row of the table  

LROT = tabla.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'We pass the data to the table

 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(LROT, 1) = Val(Txtn)  ---> LINE OF MISTAKE
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(LROT, 1).Offset(0, 1) = cbotype
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(LROT, 1).Offset(0, 2) = CDate(txtdate)
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(LROT, 1).Offset(0, 3) = cbounit
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(LROT, 1).Offset(0, 4) = names(i)
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(LROT, 1).Offset(0, 5) = IDs(i)
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(LROT, 1).Offset(0, 6) = cbojob


'We increase the number counter
Txtn = Txtn + 1

Next i

 'We empty both 2 textbox

 txtname = ""
 txtID = ""

 'We empty the matrices

 Erase names
 Erase IDs

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataBodyRange` is not set (is Nothing) until you add rows. That is why you get the error. You could use `InsertRowRange` for the first row but there is probably a neater way to do all of this.

You appear to want to insert a new row each time and populate from the data. So, use `ListObject.ListRows.Add()` to add the row:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(nombres)
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Set newRow = tabla.ListRows.Add
    newRow.Range(1, 1) = Val(Txtn)
    newRow.Range(1, 2) = cbotype
    newRow.Range(1, 3) = CDate(txtdate)
    newRow.Range(1, 4) = cbounit
    newRow.Range(1, 5) = Names(i)
    newRow.Range(1, 6) = IDs(i)
    newRow.Range(1, 7) = cbojob
    Txtn = Txtn + 1
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Andrew. It works perfectly. I really appreciatte your support and time.